# Get Magento product from url key

Tags: category, category-listing

I want to get product details from url key.

Is there a way to get product details from url_key, I am new to Magento and could not find any such way, please help I tried below code but it is not working properly.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeIds = array_keys($storeManager->getStores());
$action = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action');


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $updateAttributes = array();

    echo $row["slug"];
    echo "--->";
    $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',"URL_KEY_HERE");
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    foreach ($collection as $product) 
    {
        echo "id is ->".$product->getId();
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

Comment: Remove all unused code its correct what you do with collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$urlKey = "strive-shoulder-pack";   // add your url key which you want 

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollectionFactory->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$urlKey);
$productCollectionFactory->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($productCollectionFactory as $product) 
{
    echo "id is ->".$product->getId();
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($product->getData());
    echo "<br>";
}
```

[image]

> **Note: Only Enable Product url can check so please enter proper enable product url key**

Answer (score 1):

```
For getting product details from url key using ObjectManager:
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$prodColl = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $prodColl->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key','joust-duffle-bag');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($collection->getData());
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly don't use objectManager you can inject the used class in the construct:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory)
{
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}
```

And after that in your class use loadByAttribute function

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->loadByAttribute('url_key', $urlKey);
```

I want my answer to help you

With ObjectManager:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product = $productFactory->create();
$product->loadByAttribute('url_key', $urlKey);
```

Comment: please help me with objectmanager way as i need to do this once for adding few data to products

Comment: See my response @user1799722